# Wrong alignment in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

So i'm using the bootstrap navbar on my website and i have a search bar with a button.
The problem is that the button is appearing below the search bar and i wanted it to appear side by side.

Here is how it's looking right now: http://tinypic.com/r/2ql5u9l/9

And here's my navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DAW</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Artigos
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="artigos.php?catid=2">Desporto</a></li>
            <li><a href="artigos.php?catid=3">Educação</a></li>
            <li><a href="artigos.php?catid=1">Política</a></li> 
            <li><a href="artigos.php?catid=4">Fitness</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['id'])) { 
        echo "<li><a href='inserir_artigo.php'>Inserir Artigos</a></li>"; 
        }
        ?>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <div class="input-group">
        <form action="procurar.php" method="GET">
        <li><input type="text" class="form-control inp" placeholder="Procurar por..." name="procurar" /></li>
        <li><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button></li>
        </form>
        </div>
        </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <?php
      if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['id'])) {  

         echo  "<li><a href='editar_perfil.php?id=$iduser'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span>".$_SESSION['username']."</a></li>";
          echo "<li><a href='logout.php'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in'></span> Logout</a></li>";
           } 

           else{  
        echo "<li><a href='registo.php'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> Registar</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='login.php'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in'></span> Login</a></li>";
         }?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What has the web site you are linking to do with your question?

Answer (score 0):

Format you form properly don't put in ul tag

ref: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
...
</ul>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
...
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for search

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```